# Is is possible to reference env variables defined in codebuild inside a react app that you have in the pipeline on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, aws-codebuild

My buildspec.yml file has the following two env variables, which I am pulling from secrets manager:

Question: I am doing this, because I don't want to have a config file with the url and have it sitting in github. I was hoping to reference it in my buildspec.yml file and then pull it into my react app after build. How can I achieve this?

```html
version: 0.2

env:
  secrets-manager:
    key: API-Gateway-URL-DEV:URL
    key: API-Gateway-URL-DEV:REGION
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get those values into a file that is being deployed with your app. One way is to use jq to replace a value(s) in a file, or even write out a completely new file. So basically the config file that you didn't want to check in (wise!) should be created/updated in your build.

Comment: So these env variables that I am passing into my buildspec.yml file, they are only for use in the execution of the build if any?

Comment: Correct, those values are for use inside the build. Anything you want to do with them is up to you.